# A technical person being pushed into manager role

Tags: career-development, careers

Should I consider the role of a manager (temporarily) or start exploring other jobs for individual contributor role?

Comment: Why do they want you become a manager? It's important to find out, only then you can try to find a good strategy. *"My manager on the other hand told me that I'll get all the opportunity to work on technical stuff as before."* this raises the question once more, if this should be true then why should you become a manager? If you change to another job then probably your tasks will change too. What do they explain about that? Last but not least, what kind of manament would that be, what is their expectation?

Comment: @NeonFlash,  Option 1 and 3 are both good. For the ```Short Term```: Use option 1 till you get the citizenship, and then after that, go for the ```Long Term```: option 3 if you still want to be a technical lead instead of a manager.

Comment: this isn't an answer, but I hope that this link can help you out navigating the IC vs manager conundrum: https://charity.wtf/2017/05/11/the-engineer-manager-pendulum/

Comment: sorry, we can't help you decide what you want to do in life. There are pros and cons, and it seems like you know them

Comment: A shame to see this closed (and then edited down to nothing) when it seemed to be attracting interesting and useful answers.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the options needs to be black or white only. In many organizations, it is possible to manage a team and still be hands on in technology. Generally, in these types of roles, you yourself are in an architect type of role, working on high level frameworks and design, and the people that report to you are technical too, like engineers.

To give an example, I currently work in a very big financial services firm of about 10K employees as a technical lead in cybersecurity. I directly manage a team of 10, with the full power of a "manager". However, day to day, I work very similarly to an technical architect , designing security frameworks, planning implementation of controls, writing technical guidance documentation for junior team members etc. **Although I manage people, I am by no means divorced from hands on technical work.**

To take two of your reasons why you are hesitant to manage people (deliberately did not say being a manager):

1. **A manager can be both effective and transparent / direct in communication.**

Actually where I work in the USA, forthrightness and openess is seen as a virtue. As long as the communication tone is polite, direct in my opinion is much better than covert or shifty. With perhaps exception of personal issues between employees, there should be open communication amongst the team.  No topics that affect teams work should be considered secret, or unable to be frankly discussed in the open.

2. **Politics does not have to be construed in the negative sense, as in tearing down colleagues, or engaging in pulling rank.**

Politics can be played positively such as being confident enough to promote the work of your team to upper management so your team gets benefits (promotion, salary increase, consideration for better roles etc.) While engaging in power plays are indeed playing politics, in the culture where I come from ad places I have worked, such overt displays are often not welcome.

Comment: OP wrote " I am polite but I don't like to beat around the bush", matching well with "A manager can be both effective and transparent / direct in communication". I think that attribute is something their employer is looking for.

Comment: Every single tech-to-management colleague I have had, changed companies to return to a tech role within a year.

Answer (score 3):

> My manager on the other hand told me that I'll get all the opportunity to work on technical stuff as before.

That is a flat out lie. If you would continue to work on your stuff as before, they'd hardly need to make you a manager. That would make no sense at all. The only way this is not a lie is if you are supposed to do the "managing" part on top of your old job in tons of unpaid overtime.

Managing is done using Outlook, Word and if it gets very, *very* technical, occasionally Excel.

While there are exceptions where management is very ethical and moral, you own boss has lied to you to manipulate you into taking a job you don't want. That is what awaits you if you move further in this direction, day after day of meetings with a group of lying scumbags that will tell you anything as long as it has a chance to make you do what they want. And your job will be to be one of their peers and share their work.

Whether you are willing to suffer through this for your citizenship, or whether you are willing to take a risk to work in a job you like in a different company is something you have to weight and decide.

All things being equal and no external factors like citizenship considered, the question whether you want to work for a liar to become his sub-liar or whether you want to work in a job that you like should not even be a question.

Answer (score 0):

### Seize the opportunity

I'm going to be brutally honest with you : You probably reached the plateau of your career as an individual contributor. It is well known fact that as people age their cognitive capabilities decline, as well as their energy levels. Young engineers could work up to 16 hours a day if they are excited and enthusiastic with the project. "Old dogs", well not so much. Only thing you have going for you is experience, but in technical fields experience can quickly grow stale. Therefore, if you continue down this path, in few years you could find yourself less employable, people accepting you as last ditch option (if they cannot find anyone else) , with corresponding decrease in earnings.

On the other hand, offer by your company seems fair. They probably already know your introvert nature, dislike of meetings and communication with other people. That is why they offered you to be a tech lead, not someone in constant touch with clients. Nevertheless this is a opportunity for you to confront some of your weakness and psychological fears, and God willing overcome them. In reality, there is nothing much to lose. If you fail miserably, you could always fall back to your original role of individual contributor (in this or other company)

Finally,there is your visa/citizenship problem. I suppose you could find another company to continue employment and fulfill this 1.5 years term. But why bother with extra stress and hassle ? You now have golden chance to finish this requirement in a reasonably good setting, to settle down like you want to.

**My advice to you** is to tell your manager concerns about introvercy, conference calls, bluntness etc ... Also tell him that you were never before in managerial role and ask for some leniency and help for a few months. Then go ahead and try it. Who knows, maybe you will be successful. And if not, at least you tried and found own limits in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

## Your assessment is correct: Stand your ground

Unfortunately it is common and tempting to promote strong individual contributors into a management role and many accept, not because they want to, but because they think this is the standard career path.

What most people don't realize is that technical and management skills are almost completely orthogonal. Some people are good at both, many people are only good at one, and some people are good at none.

Becoming a good manager is difficult and hard work and it requires motivation and commitment. That's why promoting someone who actively says "no", is a terrible idea. It often ends badly, everybody involved is miserable and there is no easy way back without losing face and/or credibility.

This being said: sometimes it ends well too and people who are strong both technically and as managers are incredibly valuable and can have very rewarding careers in terms of impact, satisfaction and compensation.

**What to do?**

Before you categorically say no, please consider the potential benefit of being both a strong manager and technical contributor. If everyone goes in with  "open eyes", it may be possible to "test drive" this with minimum risk. The thing here is: you can't really know whether you like it or not, before you actually try it.

Things to ask for could be

1. Training. Make sure you can take some classes and/or seminars ideally BEFORE you start.
2. Mentoring and coaching: make sure there is someone to talk to frequently. At least once a week, daily is better. Review what decisions/interactions you had, discuss what went well and what didn't, get feedback and suggestions next steps.
3. Define, align and track success metrics for your management role. What makes a good manager and how do you stack up against that? This metric SHOULD include the amount of time you are still spending on technical work. Both you and your manager need to be fully on aligned on what "success" means.
4. Have an exit strategy from day 1. Discuss and agree on what happens if this doesn't work out for any party. How will this decision be made, what happens, and how is this communicated so that everyone still is intact.

If even with all these safeguards in place you still can't find it in your heart to give it a shot, then you just have to repeat "no": politely,  firmly & consistently.

I would still encourage you to try it, if you can do so safely. It can be incredibly rewarding, but everyone is different.

Personal example: I made this transition twice in my career and both times it went well. It's tough in the beginning but as with most things, it gets easier as you learn. I also found my limits: I grew my last department to 40+ people while still maintaining some technical component and leadership. When I was asked about the next step up (180+ people), I declined since it would have eliminated all technical work.  Everyone has their own sweet spot and it's good to know where it is.